# iPhone:How to dynamically set UIImage size , width , height and orientation?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop functionality such that to set size , width , height & orientation of UIImage dynamically in iPhone so please tell me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? You want user to be able to change it using gestures or what?

Comment: Where do you stuck? Show us your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Dynamically change image whenever view is display

Answer (score 9):

You can use `UIImageView`:

```
//get the Image
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
//create a UIImageView
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img] autorelease];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); //set these variables as you want
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone really understands your question, however:

size: (replace the width/height values wth your own)

```
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(myImageView.frame.origin.x, myImageView.frame.origin.y,width,height);
```

orientation

```
float angleInDegrees = 90; // change this value to what you want
float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (M_PI/180);
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
```